# Is there any way we can get chat data of my friends or friends of friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, chat, facebook-chat

I want to get chat history data of my friends or of people following my page.
is there any way to get that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't get it for the people who are following your page, but if you have a facebook app then you can get the messages(chat) for only the people/users who have authorised your app and have given the permission of `read_mailbox` to your app.